# I want to echo the last value in CodeIgniter by last ID

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get `echo` of the single value with `last id` but getting an error.

```
 <?php
     $querya = $this->db->select('totalqty'); 
     $querya = $this->db->get('fuel_rdirecived');
      $result = $mysqli->query($querya);
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

      echo $total= $row["totalqty"];
    ?>
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Make `return print_r($row);` before your `echo` and show please result of it.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: i want to echo single value in CodeIgniter

Comment: Message: Call to a member function query() on null

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: @Amit, do it `$this->db->select('totalqty');
$querya = $this->db->get('fuel_rdirecived');`

Comment: yes CodeIgniter

Comment: echo value 1006001000 this but last value is 1000 i need last value only

Comment: sir i have need allaways last value echo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return last record from database in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628159/how-to-return-last-record-from-database-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last value will be:

```
$querya = $this->db->select('totalqty'); 
$querya = $this->db->get('fuel_rdirecived'); 

foreach($querya->result() as $row) { 
   $lastval = $row->totalqty; 
} 
echo $lastval;
```

or

```
$this->db->select('totalqty'); 
$this->db->limit(1);
$this->db->order_by('id','desc');
$querya = $this->db->get('fuel_rdirecived');

echo $querya->result_array()
```

Comment: this is bad idea. because you are traversing all data anyhow.

Comment: This is also a solution anyway.

Comment: it's not about solution. it's about improving yourself too. check the duplicate link i have given for better solution as well as you code-improvement.

Comment: thanks sir for help for us

Comment: @Amit  i will ask you to use answers from given thread. you will get more accurate solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put array index to echo value.

```
$this->db->select('totalqty');
$this->db->from('fuel_rdirecived');
$row = $this->db->get()->result_array();
echo $total= $row[0]["totalqty"];
```

Comment: sir i have need of last value not first this code is echo first value

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Order By](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#ordering-results) and row_array with will return single array result as you want :

```
$this->db->select('totalqty');
$this->db->from('fuel_rdirecived'); 
$this->db->order_by('id','desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->row_array();

echo $result['totalqty'];
```